# Execution environment of the script (eshell vs bash)

Tags: emacs, eshell

How to determine inside a script - whether it has been executed from a eshell or from a normal shell (bash, etc.)?

Comment: It might be worth logging a bug report for this (`M-x report-emacs-bug`), as it seems entirely reasonable that `eshell` should add similar environment variables to those available with the other Emacs shell options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add (setenv "EMACS" "t") to ~/.emacs. So the behavior would be the same in all emacs shells.

Comment: Of course if the intention is to write a portable script which happens to behave nicely for anyone running it under eshell, this won't help.

Answer (score 5):

Eshell doesn't set any particular environment variable. You can check `$TERM`: it's set to `dumb` under Eshell.

A more precise check would look at the parent process of the script

```
if [ -t 1 ] && [ "$TERM" = "dumb" ] && [ "$(ps -o comm= -p $PPID)" = "emacs" ]; then
  echo "This looks a lot like eshell"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

I initially marked this as a duplicate of [How do I tell a shell that it is running from within Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130073/how-do-i-tell-a-shell-that-it-is-running-from-within-emacs), but I think the answer there is flawed or outdated, as although it explicitly mentions `eshell`, it only seems to apply to `shell` and `term` and `ansi-term`. `eshell` must be the only kind of shell you can run in Emacs that *doesn't* set an obvious environment variable?

Comment: Correct - the answer for those question is not suitable here: `echo $EMACS` in both cases gives nothing for eshell whithin emacs and for bash, etc. So please unmark this question as 'duplicate'.

Comment: The vote can't be removed, but as it requires several votes to close a question as a duplicate, there's really nothing to worry about.